# jquery.ajaxSetup() && .load() == I don't like it

Tags: jquery

I have this problem when using merely `load()` was sufficient, then of course I entered into caching related problems. So tried to fix it with `ajaxSetup()` but now I run into bigger problem which is `Object not found` error.

Here is the code:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false;
});

//podmeni definicija klik akcije
$("#podmeni a").click(function(){
    var link=$(this).attr("href");
   $("#tekst").load(link,function(){
       //visina
       $("#podmeni").height(($("#desno").height()-$("#logo").height()));
   });
   return false;
});
```

Thank you ;)

Comment: There shouldn't be a semicolon after `cache: false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have an error here

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false;
});
```

should be

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false
});
```

Anyway, if you have cache problems in IE this won't solve your issue i fear

Answer (score 4):

Remove the extra `;` after `cache: false`.